# can't store data into laravel user model

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am trying to make a crud for the user model through API requests, I already have made auth using sanctum and UI scaffolding

this is the Route in my api.php file

```php
Route::post('/customer', function() {

    request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    return User::create([
        'name' => request('name'),
        'email' => request('email'),
        'password' => request('password'),
    ]);

});
```

but when i pass the request

```sh
POST http://localhost:8000/api/customer HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "name" : "xxx",
    "email": "xx@gmail.com",
    "password": "wqaxszcde"
}
```

it returns 419 unknown status

Comment: It's a CORS issue. Try setting `SESSION_DOMAIN ` and `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS ` in the `.env`

Comment: @jeremykenedy it is already set up
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost

Comment: @TimLewis it's a typo when posting the question i miss wrote it, it is password